# How to use MATCH, INDIRECT and dynamic references in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, match

I'm trying to return a value for an indirect() using a cell value which is not hard-coded.

I have a sheet called AB SOW #1. In cell D19 of AB SOW #1, I have the text "Weekly Billable". First, I verified INDIRECT works using the following:

```
=INDIRECT("AB SOW #1!D19")
```

That gave me "Weekly Billable" as expected.  Cool.

Next, I verified MATCH works with:

```
=MATCH("Weekly Billable","AB SOW #1!D19")
```

That gave me 1 as expected.  Also cool.

Next, I put "AB SOW #1" in cell A7 of my destination sheet and tried the following:

```
=MATCH("Weekly Billable",INDIRECT("AB SOW #1!D19"))
```

That gives me #NA with the error tip: Did not find value 'Weekly Billable' in MATCH evaluation.

I'm ultimately trying to do something like this:

```
=MATCH("Weekly Billable",INDIRECT(""& $A7 & "'!D:D")
```

Where MATCH searches the entire D column of the sheet name in A7 for the value of Weekly Billable.  These tests above were my first tries at solving the problem.

Any advice into what I'm missing here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED, but please try:

```
=MATCH("Weekly Billable",INDIRECT($A7&"!D:D"),0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - that gives me the same #NA with the error tip: Did not find value 'Weekly Billable' in MATCH evaluation.  I appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I'd completely forgotten about checking for spaces.  Silly mistake on my part.